# Reverse each word of a string in C

Tags: c, beginner, strings, interview-questions

I had this interview question like a year ago and was asked to code, on a piece of paper, how to reverse each word of a string.  Since I am used to Java, I proposed the obvious answer of using split + reverse, which are native commands in Java.  I was then told I couldn't use those, so I floundered and ended up with a really terrible solution (even though it technically would've worked).

Anyway, it was bugging me lately, so I gave it a shot in straight C, which I am not very good at, so it took me a good while to actually get it working.

I was wondering:

1. Is this a good solution?
2. Have I forgotten anything obvious?
3. Have I done anything non-kosher in the C world?

Again, I'm not very good at C, so even small points will probably help me out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverseString(char* start, char* end){
   while (start < end){
      char temp = *start;
      *start = *end;
      *end = temp;
      ++start;
      --end;
   }   
}

char* word_start_index(char* p)
{
    while((*p != '\0') && (*p == ' ')){
        ++p;    
    }

    if(*p == '\0')
        return NULL;
    else
        return p;
}

char* word_end_index(char* p)
{
    while((*p != '\0') && (*p != ' ')){
        ++p;
    }

    return p-1;
} 

void main(){
    char arr[] = "kevin is a good programmer";
    char* test = arr;

    while (test != '\0'){
        char* curWordStart = word_start_index(test);
        if (curWordStart == NULL)
            break;
        char* curWordEnd = word_end_index(curWordStart);
        reverseString(curWordStart, curWordEnd); 
        test = curWordEnd + 1;
    }
    printf("%s \n", arr);
}
```

Also, would taking a different approach, like in higher level languages of breaking the string into an array of strings (so I guess a 2D array of chars), then stepping through and reversing each one, be a good approach as well? I thought about this first and was unable to hash it out.

Comment: Another thing that you need to consider is that words are not always terminated by a space. Punctuation also counts!.:,;?
And, being awkward, what about numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a few issues with in your code:

- Consistency in naming - use either camelCase or not_camel_case but don't
  mix
- consistency in braces.  The opening brace for a function goes in the first
  column.
- `word_start_index` and `word_end_index` should take a `const` parameter
- `word_start_index` is the same as `strspn(string, " ");` or if you are also
  looking for punctuation, `strspn(string, " \t\n.,;:");`
- `word_end_index` - as for `word_start_index` but use `strcspn` (note the
  'c')
- `word_end_index` as a function (ie not in your context) fails for an empty
  string or a string starting with a space  (it returns the char before the
  string starts).
- variable `test` in `main()` is misnamed. I would prefer something that shows it
  is a string.
- the test `while (test != '\0')` in `main()` is wrong - should be `*test !=
  '\0'`.
  Your loop always exits from the `break`
- no return or parameters in main()

Also, arguably the position of the stars in your pointers is wrong.  I prefer `char* p` to be written `char *p`, which makes it clear that it is p that takes the star. Consider code such as `char* a, b;`. This is bad because it gives the impression that b is a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  Do you think taking a different approach like in higher level languages of breaking the string into an array of string (so I guess a 2-d array of chars), then stepping through and reversing each one would be good approach as well?  I thought about this first and was unable to hash it out.

Comment: No, your approach is fine

Comment: OK, thanks for the details, I was definitely unclear about how some of the pointers need to be declared and compared and had some trial and error there.  The camel case issues were just a result of copy pasting a bit off the web, but again thanks for the help.

Comment: @WilliamMorris, hello, what is the benefit of changing the parameters to const? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I like it; nice and logical and easy to follow.

The only change I would make is the test for space.

```
*p == ' '
```

I would replace this with

```
isspace(*p)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also met this question during a interview several years before, the string was null-terminated and separated by spaces.
my idea was same as yours, just save some lines of code, comments in line.

```
// Reverse the characters between pointer p and q
void ReverseWord(char* p, char* q)
{
    while(p < q)
    {
        char t = *p ;
        *p++   = *q ;
        *q--   = t ;
    }
}


// Reverse all words in a sentence.
void ReverseSentence(char *s)
{
    char *p = s ;   // point to the start position of a word
    char *q = s ;   // point to the end position of a word(white space or '\0')

    while(*q != '\0') // While string not ends
    {
        if (*q == ' ') // Get a word?
        {
            ReverseWord(p, q - 1) ;
            q++ ; // move to next word
            p = q ;
        }
        else
            q++ ;
    }

    ReverseWord(p, q - 1) ; // Reverse the last word
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine is also very similiar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void reverse(char *p, char *q)
{
    while (p<q)
    {
        char t = *p;
        *p++   = *q;
        *q--   =  t;
    }
}

char *reverse_each_word(char* str)
{
    char *p, *q = str;
    while(*q)
    {
        p = q; while(*p && !isalnum(*p)) p++; // Skip non-word chars
        q = p; while(*q &&  isalnum(*q)) q++; // Skip     word chars
        if(*p) reverse(p, q-1);
    }    
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "An answer on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18229";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%s\n", reverse_each_word(str));    
    return 0;
}
```